# MVC Request.ClientCertificate is not null but with empty properties problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, certificate, client-certificates

In my ASP.NET MVC Application, "System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ClientCertificate" NEVER seems to be null. However the properties of certificate is dummy. It includes empty byte array, and valid from/to dates are set to current request time, no issuer, subject. etc... (all set to null).

cert.IsPresent is false. So, actually this property must have been null.

[image: Client Cert instance watch status]

I cannot figure out what sets this certificate on request?

I tried "Ignore" option selected on IIS SSL Settings and I do not send client cert on request. But MVC still creates dummy certificate instance on request.

Comment: why do you want it to be null ?

Comment: Because I am trying to pass my own certificate to server, but this situtation prevents others.

Comment: Please define the basic problem.  Are you trying to pass CA issued certificate form client browser to server? What you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Only when the SSL communication is established between the client and the server, this function method will have a return value. A typical example is through the IIS certificate authentication feature.
[image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/iisclientcertificatemappingauthentication/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/configure-many-to-one-client-mappings
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/configuring-one-to-one-client-certificate-mappings
After disabling other authentication modes, the server requires a client certificate when the client tries to access the website hosted on the server. once the SSL communication is established, this method will return the client certificate and the server certificate.

```
public ActionResult About()
    {
        var result = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ClientCertificate;
        ViewBag.Message = result.Subject+result.ServerSubject;
        return View();
    }
```

[image]

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.